# Selenium Driver Installation Issue

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Encountering this problem
`raise ValueError(f"There is no such driver by url {resp.url}") ValueError: There is no such driver by url`

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_121.0.6167

```
service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

Not able to install drivers for newer version

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code snippet to install selenium service.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time

s = Service("chromedriver.exe")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)

driver.get("https://www.google.com")

# Perform actions on the website if needed

# Add a delay before closing the browser
time.sleep(1000)  # Adjust the delay time as needed

# Close the browser window explicitly
driver.quit()
```

Comment: In this case we need to update the chrome driver every time, because as i'm using the latest version of browser